# Ajax requests in jquery mobile dialog

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I have a problem...

I'm working on a dialog in which there're two buttons that are linked with two different actions.
I'd like to have two Ajax requests when the buttons are clicked.
I tried every kind of javascript scripts but it dosn't work...

I premise that in the page of the dialog I haven't included jquery mobile scripts (in the guide is said that dialogs don't need links to the script if they're called as dialogs through a link [data-rel])

**It seems that inside dialog external javascript code isn't loaded...**
This is a problem...

Do you think it's better to call the dialog with a simple link (without data-rel and with data-ajax=false) and replace data-role=page with data-role=dialog (I mean inside the dialog page).

Thank you

Best regards

Luca

Comment: You haven't been very specific with your question and answer. If you think this info is useful to the community, could you add a small amount of sample code of what you did wrong and how you fixed it, that way someone else can learn from this? Otherwise this question should probably be removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution through Jquery mobile forum...

The problem is that for dialogs the javascript code must be wrote inside the page div and not at the end of the body (the classical position of javascript code).
So your code will be loaded and will work...